# Cannot find the xeus-cling kernel in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, xeus-cling

I would like to try the C++ kernel in Jupyter notebooks.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.01. The existing answer cover Windows which was not supported at the time.

I already have a bunch of conda environments, mainly Python but a couple of Julia kernels as well. I normally launch Jupyter Notebooks from the Anaconda Navigator: upon clicking on the "New" I see all these environments (Julia 1.8.1, Python 3 ipykernel, as well as the conda environments). Once the new notebook is created, I find the them all again under Kernels / change Kernel menu.

To get a C++ kernel, I followed the steps in [Xeus-Cling:Run C++ code in Jupyter notebook](https://learnopencv.com/xeus-cling-run-c-code-in-jupyter-notebook/).

To summarise:

```
conda create -n xeus-cling
source activate xeus-cling
```

hence creating and activating a new conda environment (NOTE: I tried it all again using `conda activate`  instead of `source activate` , although I believe they should be equivalent, are they not).

Further I install Xeus-cling, as per instructions

```
conda install -c conda-forge xeus-cling
```

and that should be it.
I then go

```
source activate xeus-cling
jupyter-notebook
```

but contrary to the snapshot in the article, there is not trace of any C++ kernel, nor of the recenty create Xeus-cling conda environment (which however shows up if I issue `conda env list`.

When creating a new environment in the past, it would not show on the Jupyter Notebook "New" tab until ipykernel was installed, I guess this should be taken care in this case somehow by xeus-cling, but I am clearly not making it work.

If it could be of any relevance, the first time I tried the command
`jupyter notebooks` got unrecognised. I installed with `sudo apt`  and it did open a notebook, without C++ kernels. I deactivated/deleted this environment, and upon creating a new one, the command `jupyter notebooks` got recognised, which puzzled me-

Comment: As per duplicate, the environment with `jupyter` and `nb_conda_kernels` should be activated, not the kernel. The kernel will be discovered automatically with `xeus-cling` - no need for any additional packages (e.g., `ipykernel` which is for Python kernels and not relevant).

Comment: ok thanks, the bottom lie here is installing `nb_conda_kernels`, to my partial defence this is not menyioned in the tutoral I linked, thanks a lot

Comment: No worries - unfortunately there's a lot of outdated and half-baked info out there on best practices for Conda + Jupyter. Once bad practices get entrenched, it's rather difficult getting better info into prominence.

Comment: i see, thanks again your input was very useful